# gRPC Client->Server connection failed - The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, grpc

I have build the gRPC pair (client+Greeter Service) as [MS described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/grpc/grpc-start?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio)

and tried to run. I have received

the Server log:

```
dbug: Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.Internal.GrpcServiceBinder[1]
Added gRPC method 'SayHello' to service 'Greet.Greeter'. Method type: 'Unary', route pattern: '/Greet.Greeter/SayHello'.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Now listening on: http://localhost:50051
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Content root path: E:\gRPC\GrpcGreeter\GrpcGreeter
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[29]
Connection id "0HLNJ0DILMG0A": HTTP/2 connection error.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http2.Http2ConnectionErrorException: HTTP/2 connection error (PROTOCOL_ERROR): Invalid HTTP/2 connection preface.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http2.Http2Connection.ParsePreface(ReadOnlySequence1& buffer, SequencePosition& consumed, SequencePosition& examined) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http2.Http2Connection.TryReadPrefaceAsync() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http2.Http2Connection.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication1 application)
```

the client's log

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.IO.IOException: The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response.
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.FillAsync()
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ReadNextResponseHeaderLineAsync(Boolean foldedHeadersAllowed)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithNtConnectionAuthAsync(HttpConnection connection, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts) at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall2.SendAsync(HttpClient client, HttpRequestMessage message)
at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall`2.GetResponseHeadersAsync()
E:\gRPC\GrpcGreeterClient\GrpcGreeterClient\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\GrpcGreeterClient.exe (process 17980) exited with code -532462766.
Press any key to close this window . . .
```

I have added the Firewall rule for 50051 but again the same errors. 
How to fix the error?
What I do wrong?

Comment: its listening on localhost:50051? It surely needs to listen on either all IPs or at least the main IP for the network that is going to be contacted on - but it looks like you mke contact - you need to check what the response is.. other than "error"

Comment: I have found a reason of the bug: MS doc contains errors, and their github code samples too. Again: need to be careful ;-)

Answer (score 0):

1. The ASPNET.Core doc site contains errors:
   My client app + the gRPC server app from github works. 
   The reasons are in hardcoded URLs and in client's Program.cs:

   var channel = new Channel("localhost:50051", 
   ChannelCredentials.Insecure);

vs

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
// The port number(50051) must match the port of the gRPC server.
 httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:50051");
```

2. Also, look at launchSettings.json file and be sure that it contains correct data.

Comment: I have the same problem. I know the ports match because I had to change them for another issue. where did you use `var channel = new Channel("localhost:50051", ChannelCredentials.Insecure);`